# If I relax some constraints, can I get an algorithmic shortcut on Approximate Nearest Neighbors?

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I'm looking for an algorithm with the fastest time per query for a problem similar to nearest-neighbor search, but with two differences:

- I need to only approximately confirm (tolerating Type I and Type II error) the existence of a neighbor within some distance *k* or return the approximate distance of the nearest neighbor.
- I can query many at once

I'd like better throughput than the approximate nearest neighbor libraries out there (https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) which seem better designed for single queries. In particular, the algorithmic relaxation of the first criteria seems like it should leave room for an algorithmic shortcut, but I can't find any solutions in the literature nor can I figure out how to design one.

Here's my current best solution, which operates at about 10k queries / sec on per CPU. I'm looking for something close to an order-of-magnitude speedup if possible.

```
sample_vectors = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(10000, vector_size))
new_vectors = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(100000, vector_size))

import annoy
ann = annoy.AnnoyIndex(vector_size, metric='hamming')
for i, v in enumerate(sample_vectors):
    ann.add_item(i, v)
ann.build(20)

for v in new_vectors:
    print(ann.get_nns_by_vector(v, n=1, include_distances=True))
```

Comment: What is a acceptable calculation time? Can you give a few Data samples as code?

Comment: Hamming distance should never be computed at the word level, it should be computed at the bit level. That is easily an order of magnitude speed  up there.

Comment: Yes, one possible order-of-magnitude speedup could be a specialized algorithm to work only on bitstrings. I did not find such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the solutions, they gave me some ideas, but I'll answer my own question as I found a solution that mostly resolved my question, and maybe it will help someone else in the future.

I used one of the libraries linked in the benchmarks, [hnswlib](https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib) as it not only has slightly improved performance over annoy, but it also has a bulk-query option. Hnswlib's algorithm also allows a highly flexible performance/accuracy tradeoff in favor of performance, which is well-suited for the highly-error tolerant approximate checking I want to do. Further, even though the parallelization improvements are far from linear per-core, it's still something. The above factors combined for a ~5x speedup in my particular situation.

As ldog said, your milage may vary depending on your problem statement.

Comment: Yes, I found hnswlib to be the highest performer out of the benchmarked algorithms. However, a custom implementation of the algorithm in [1] that I described above gave me about 10-100x improvement in perfromance over hnswlib, with higher recall. Depending how much work you would like to put into this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit skeptical of benchmarks such as the one you have linked, as in my experience I have found that the definition of the problem at hand far outweighs in importance the merits of any one algorithm across a set of *other* (possibly similar looking) problems.

More simply put, an algorithm being a high performer on a given benchmark does **not** imply it will be a higher performer on the problem you care about. Even small or apparently trivial changes to the formulation of your problem can significantly change the performance of any fixed set of algorithms.

That said, given the specifics of the problem you care about I would recommend the following:

- use the cascading approach described in the paper [[1](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Cheng_Fast_and_Accurate_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)]
- use SIMD operations (either SSE on intel chips or GPUs) to accelerate, the nearest neighbour problem is one where operations closer to the metal and parallelism can really shine
- tune the parameters of the algorithm to maximize your objective; in particular, the algorithm of [[1](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Cheng_Fast_and_Accurate_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)] has a few easy to tune parameters which will dramatically trade performance for accuracy, make sure you perform a [grid search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#Grid_search) over these parameters to set them to the *sweet spot* for your problem

Note: I have recommended the paper [[1](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Cheng_Fast_and_Accurate_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)] because I have tried many of the algorithms listed in the benchmark you linked and found them all inferior (for the task of image reconstruction) to the approach listed in [[1](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Cheng_Fast_and_Accurate_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)] while at the same time being much more complicated than [[1](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Cheng_Fast_and_Accurate_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)], both undesirable properties. YMMV depending on your problem definition.